# Formatting my email sent with mail() through PHP, and IIS7

Tags: php, html, email, gmail, sendmail

First thing. My code works. I have my SMTP information set up correctly in IIS7's sendmail.ini, and i'm using gmail. What I have is a shopping cart for ordering food.

In my cart.php page, I have the print output pulling in the users choices:

```
$printoutput .= "<table width='500' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
                            <tr><td> <strong>Order Item # ". ($i+1) ."</strong></td></tr>
                            <tr><td> ". $product_name . "</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>$" . $price . ".00</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>". $displayoptions . "</td></tr></table>

                            <table height='1%' width='500' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td></td></tr></table>";

            $i++;
```

This output looks perfect in a web browser. Later in the code, I use a form to post the `$printoutput` and name it `order`. But on my `email.php` page, I use

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['order'])){
  $order = $_POST['order'];
}
```

and then

```
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $order, $headers);
```

well like I said, I can just simply `echo $order` and it looks perfect in the web browser. But when actually sent as an email, I get an email with ALL of the html mark up with it. I've tried a few things, but nothing is formatting my information the way I want it to. Does anyone know how I can get this to basically format correctly in an email?

I'd like to have my information simply listed like this:
Order Item #
Product Name
Price
Options

But currently the output in the email has a ton of extra spaces, and shows all the HTML.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you specifying in the headers that you're sending an HTML email, not plain text?

Comment: I don't think I am. I will research that and see where to add the correct code to specify HTML.

Comment: Ah yes! That was it! THANK YOU @Mark Parnell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_mail_mail.asp

```
<?php
$to = "somebody@example.com, somebodyelse@example.com";
$subject = "HTML email";

$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML email</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
";

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so very much @esdebon! That worked! I'll accept this answer when SO will let me (5 minutes).